# How does SSL work on Re-directs?

Tags: browser, ssl

I am interested in trying to figure out exactly what is going on when a user types in, for example

```
https://www.bing.com
```

which lands them on

```
http://www.bing.com
```

If you'll notice, www.bing.com apparently doesnt support https, so the page returned has no cert associated with it. Shouldn't the browser complain about this? What's more, is that when looking at the HTTP headers, I never actually see a ridirect or anything that indicates this page returned is not the https version (guess I was expecting some indication this happened).

For another example, gmail does something similar -

I go to `https://gmail.com`

and I end up on `mail.google.com` or `accounts.google.com` depending on whether I'm logged in or not. At least these sites give me a cert, unlike bing, but how come the browser doesn't complain that the URL's are mismatched? It seems like I should also get a cert for gmail.com is that case, right? (the cert on the gmail redirect is good for mail.google.com, but makes no mention wildcard or otherwise of gmail.com)

Comment: When I load `https://www.bing.com` in Firefox (v20) I get a certificate error.  What browser are you using?

Comment: firefox 16.01 and 19...it is odd though, that i have gotten a cert warning occaisionally trying these experiements in firefox 16, but i haven't quite figured out the steps to recreate it.

Comment: i'll update my browser tomorrow just to see if i get any different results. If I do, I'll update my post.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special going on.  It's a simple HTTP redirect, but you'll only see it **if you ignore the SSL certificate error**.  (https://www.bing.com currently serves a certificate issued to akamai.)  Remember, once you tell your browser to ignore the cert error, it will generally remember that choice for the rest of the session.

If you instruct your browser to ignore the SSL certificate error, the following happens *inside a SSL-encrypted connection*:

```
GET https://www.bing.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.bing.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.73 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: AkamaiGHost
Content-Length: 0
Location: http://www.bing.com/
Date: Thu, 02 May 2013 22:02:28 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

There's no rule against a HTTPS site redirecting to plain HTTP<sup>1</sup>, so the browser just does a normal request for http://www.bing.com.  Since we're now on a plain HTTP page, there's nothing to display (warning or otherwise) regarding certificates.

<sup>1 - except in certain situations involving `POST` requests, where some browsers issue warnings.</sup>

The other sites you mention work similarly, except the redirect from gmail.com is to https://mail.google.com.  mail.google.com has its own certificate, distinct from https://www.gmail.com's certificate.

Comment: I think this is all stuff that I mostly already knew. I guess what I'm wondering about is why the browser doesnt get suspicious when the TCP connection is established, and is not immediately followed by an SSL hello. In the gmail case, isnt the browser expecting to have to decrypt that very first HTTP 302? It's like it sees its a 302 and doesnt try to finish the ssl handshake until the redirect has happened. This is even as the initial client side HTTP request was wrapped in SSL headers, right?

Comment: Maybe to put the question in an easier term - does the browser allow the HTTP redirect take precedence over everything else?

Comment: A https connection necessarily requires the TLS/SSL handshake to complete before any HTTP data can be transmitted.  Sending anything but a TLS/SSL handshake at the beginning of a connection would be an error.  So for https​://bing.com, we connect to bing.com:443, do a SSL handshake (ignoring cert errors), and then send a HTTP request for /.  The response says 302 to http​://bing.com, so we close the connection and open a new one to bing.com:80, and send a HTTP request for /.  The 200 response contains Bing.

Comment: ...in the case of Gmail, regardless of whether you request http​://gmail.com/ or https​://gmail.com, the server responds with a 301 to https​://mail.google.com/mail/.

Comment: I guess what I am saying is that the browser must be pre-configured to ignore that first cert error, since the client starts the whole conversation with the first part of an SSL handshake (by specifying :443 and setting the appropriate bits in the first contact with the server)

Comment: Right.  Once you ignore a cert error, your browser doesn't warn you again for the rest of your session -- which is probably why it appeared https​://bing.com was working for you.